# Concat two Ienumerables of different types

Tags: c#

I have two instances of `IEnumerable<T>` (with the Different T). I want to combine  both of them .

1. `IEnumerable<ClassA>`
2. `IEnumerable<ClassB>`

Both in CLass A and ClassB i have one common property .Lets say for example it is EmpId ..

Is there a build-in method in .Net to do that or do I have to write it myself?

Comment: Define "combine" here; do you want a concatenation of the sequence defined by the common property? a union? an intersection? an "inner join"? a one-sided outer-join? a full outer-join? what? Do you have an example input and output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot combine two sequences of different types in one sequence, unless you project some of their properties in a common type and create a sequence of this type.

For instance, let we have the two following classes:

```
public class A
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class B
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public bool Sex { get; set; }
}
```

Furthermore, let that you have two sequences, one containing objects of type `classA` and the other containing objects of type `classB`. Then, if you declare a third type called `classCommon`, that would contain the commont properties of `classA` and `classB`,

```
public class classCommon
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

you could try the following:

```
var result = listA.Select(x => new classCommon { ID = x.ID, Age = x.Age })
                  .Concat(listB.Select(x => new classCommon{ ID = x.ID, Age = x.Age });
```

Comment: Or you create a base reference list, such as `IEnumerable<object>` in which case you can merge the enumerables, so saying "you cannot" is a bit misleading.

Comment: Hello AdamHouldsworth,

Thanks for the reply.Could you please help me for the below requirement..
public class A
{
    public int CID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
public class B
{
    public int CID { get; set; }
    public intSNum{ get; set; }

}
public commom M {
     public int CID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
     public int SNum{ get; set; }
}
Ienumerable<M> =Combination of A and B with all values
Here one CID can contain Multiple SNUM .

Comment: @user3543884 could you please post this to another question, in order to be more readable. Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you can extract the common property to a common interface, let's say `IEmployee`, then you could just [`Cast()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb341406%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and then [Concatenate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb302894%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) the collections:

```
classAItems.Cast<IEmployee>().Concat(classBItems)
```

Note that this will only iterate over those `IEnumerable`s on demand. If you want to create a `List` containing the content of both sequences at the time you combined them, you can use [`ToList()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb342261%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
List<IEmployee> all = classAItems.Cast<IEmployee>().Concat(classBItems).ToList();
```

You can do the same if you only need an array using [`ToArray()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb298736%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You can get the concatenated common property easily enough:

```
var empIds = first.Select(x => x.EmpId).Concat(second.Select(x => x.EmpId));
```

If this is not what you are after, you will have to be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

You can concat them with respect to the lowest common denominator, which is `object` in you case:

```
IEnumerable<ClassA> e1 = new List<ClassA>();
IEnumerable<ClassB> e2 = new List<ClassB>();

IEnumerable<object> c = e1.Cast<object>()
                          .Concat(e2.Cast<object>());
```

But this will not give you much, you will have to runtime check of object type in `c` collection.

You can create a better common denominator, like some interface `IClass` which has property `EmpId` and is implemented by both `ClassA` and `ClassB`.

If you do not care about Intellisense, you can try to use `dynamic`:

```
IEnumerable<ClassA> e1 = new List<ClassA>() { new ClassA() { A = 1 } };
IEnumerable<ClassB> e2 = new List<ClassB>();

IEnumerable<dynamic> c = e1.Cast<object>()
                           .Concat(e2.Cast<object>());
int a = c.First().A;
```

In above code, `a` will properly result in `1`.